# MySqlConversionException issue

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date

i want to insert date now into mysql database

i need to convert the format but it didn't worked

this is my code
    Dim now As Datetime  = Datetime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

but it didn't worked either

as i google this i found out that the problem is because the parameter in my connection string `AllowDateTimeZero=True`

but when i tried to add it in my conn string, it stil didn't worked. could someone help me about this

i've spent 2 hours trying to fix this, but it's not worked..

thanks before

Comment: Why do you think that you need to convert the format? A datetime value doesn't have any specific format.

Answer (score 0):

In VB, a DateTime data type holds the number if TICKs that have occured since 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM. When you convert the DateTime.Now into a string, then put it into another DateTime, VB must convert the string "1985-12-31" into the number of ticks.

The code you posted...

```
Dim now As Datetime = Datetime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

...does nothing except introduce the possibility of issues due to culture difference in DateTime.

What you should have done is posted the code you use to insert the data into MySQL. If you are using a command and a non-parameterized INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyDate) VALUES (" & Datetime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & ")
```

If it is parameterized, as it should be:

```
cmd.AddParameterWithValue("p1",Datetime.Now)
```

If you are using the EF or some type of DBML:

```
MyTable.MyDate = Datetime.Now
```